# Can we autoclose SL4A terminal, after script execution ends

Tags: android, python, scripting, sl4a

When a script ends, SL4A terminal takes over and flashes: 
"Process has expired. Close terminal?", prompting me (user) to say Yes / No.

Is there someway that the SL4A terminal dialog can be suppressed, so that after the script execution is completed, it SL4A silents quits ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. This is documented under:

```
 sl4a/docs/AppInventor.md
```

file, and the right way to launch the SL4A application, is to use the Intent.action:

```
Action: com.googlecode.android_scripting.action.LAUNCH_BACKGROUND_SCRIPT
```